# JavaFX 8.0: How to change the focus traversal key?

Tags: javafx, traversal

The regular focus traversal keys are TAB for moving focus forward and SHIFT+TAB for moving focus backward. And now I want to use ENTER key instead of TAB. Are there any idea for this?

Qinn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have done it:

```
rootNode.addEventFilter( KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
{
    Robot  eventRobot = new Robot();

    @Override
    public void handle( KeyEvent KV )
    {
        switch ( KV.getCode() )
        {
            case ENTER :
            {
                if ( ! (KV.getTarget() instanceof TextArea) )
                {
                    eventRobot.keyPress( java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB );
                    eventRobot.keyRelease( java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB );
                    KV.consume();
                }
                break;
            }
            case TAB :
            {
                if ( ! (KV.getTarget() instanceof TextArea) )
                {
                    KV.consume();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can moving focus with key ENTER according to the codes supported by Jurgen. However, the key TAB can still moving the focus at same time. Are there any advice to prevent this?

Comment: I think it's better to use KeyCombination...
ENTER = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER,KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);

Answer (score 1):

I Think it would be better off if you use two classes:
`KeyCombination` for a more precise key checking along with
`KeyboardShortcutsHandler` to move focus.

So there's no need to use a Robot to send tab key

```
final KeyCombination ENTER = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER);

rootNode.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent KV) -> {
    EventTarget tgt = KV.getTarget();
    if (ENTER.match(KV)) {

        KeyboardShortcutsHandler ksh = new KeyboardShortcutsHandler();
        ksh.traverse((Node) tgt, Direction.NEXT);
        KV.consume();

    } else if ( ! (KV.getTarget() instanceof TextArea) ) {

        KV.consume();

    }
});
```

Comment: Be advised that KeyboardShortcutsHandler is not public API though !  So this is not really a good idea I think.